# Low Voltage cable run thru Flexible Aluminum Pipe

Tags: ducts, data-wiring

Are there any code issues with running CAT6 and Coax thru flexible duct that is not part of a ventilation system?

Basically I want to use something like this as conduit into an unfinished attic instead of PVC:
http://www.homedepot.com/p/Speedi-Products-3-in-x-96-in-Round-Aluminum-Flex-Pipe-EX-AF-396/202907340

The attic is dusty and full of insulation.  So I want something flexible that can curve back up to keep the dust and insulation from falling into the living space/closet

Comment: I agree with the exception of a plenum. If the wires are in a air handling space they need to be plenum rated other than that in an attic/ wall standard wire is ok.

Comment: Is there a reason you can't run a conduit instead?

Comment: @bib - not really true. http://www.sdmmag.com/articles/84601-what-technicians-need-to-know-about-cable-the-nec

Answer (score 2):

May I introduce you to smurf tube? It's actually designed for the job, and meets your flexibility requirement.

[image: Image from Home Depot, does not constitute an endorsement of home depot as a source]

(Technically ENT (Electrical Nonmetallic Tubing), and it comes in non-smurfy orange as well as smurf blue.)